# TextView not displaying full text in BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

My text is not being shown correctly despite having  `maxLines="10"`

[image: Text being displayed incorrectly]

Here is my XML code for the TextView

```
<com.example.moveapplication.utils.MAFTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOwnerAbout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:maxLines = "10"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icAbout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icAbout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icAbout"
    tools:text="Agent for Jazzy flats" />
```

Tried to implement scrolling programmatically but nothing happens

```
uAbout.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

**Code for my custom TextView**

```
class MAFTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView (context, attrs){
init {
    applyFont()
}

private fun applyFont() {
    val typeface: Typeface =
        Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "Montserrat-Regular.ttf")
    setTypeface(typeface)
}
}
```

Comment: Since you are using a custom _TextVIew_, it would be helpful to share the custom code.

Comment: @Cheticamp I have updaed my question an provided code for my custom _TextView_

Comment: Well, that didn't help. :-) Are you constraining the height of your bottom sheet? That would limit the height of the text view. Take a look at the layout with Android Studio's _Layout Inspector_ to see if anything jumps out. If you are still stuck, it would be useful to see the bottom sheet layout and how you display it.